# External HDD doesn't show up in boot manager

Tags: linux, windows-10, hard-drive

I installed a Linux partition on one of my older laptops, I bought a new one recently running on windows and thought of plugging in the old harddisk to the new one by means of a converter (HDD to USB) although I can reach the partitions through a Linux file explorer on Windows, I am unable to boot from the device.

Please Help!!

Comment: "older laptop" likely means BIOS. Anything you can buy nowadays is UEFI. It's simply not compatible. Please learn UEFI and its requirements before attempting to install any new OS.

Comment: my older laptop was had on InsydeH20 bios, and I am not installing an OS, I just need to boot from the hard drive